# enviar formulário para outra página html

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um formulário e quero enviar ele para outra página, que é um contrato. Os dados enviados são para preencher o contrato. Utilizei o script em anexo, porém, ele só envia um campo.

```js
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
        var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
        }

        var sn = getParameterByName('pt1');
        document.getElementById("vj2p1").innerHTML = sn;
```

Comment: O seguinte código é justamente uma função pra pegar um parâmetro, poderia enviar o código completo do script que está tentando implementar?

Comment: Seria mais fácil usar php ou json, mais já que escolheu javascrip, não seria melhor usar ajax/jquery para fazer esse envio?

Answer (score 1):

## Explicação:

Quando você envia o formulário da página 1 pra página 2 ele cria "Parâmetros" na url da página 2

Por exemplo: `http://127.0.0.1/pagina2.html?nome=Fulano&nascimento=01/01/1990`

A função que você está usando pega esses parâmetros da url, mas, somente, um por vez.

> ```
>    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
>        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
>        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
>        var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
>        results = regex.exec(url);
>        if (!results) return null;
>        if (!results[2]) return '';
>        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
>    }
> ```

Ou seja, se você quer pegar mais de um parâmetro e colocar ele em algum lugar, você vai precisar colocar um por um na página 2
**Como no exemplo a seguir:**
Se na sua página 2 há um html como esse:

```
    <div class="conteudo">
        Seu nome é: <span id="nome"></span><br>
        Sua data de nascimento é: <span id="nascimento"></span>
    </div>
```

Para imprimir os valores dos parâmetros em cada span desses, você precisará identificar cada span, como eu fiz dando um "id" pro span.
por exemplo, se você quiser pegar o cpf, seria da seguinte forma: `<span id="cpf"></span>`
Entendida essa parte, já deu pra perceber que você vai ter que criar uma variável pra salvar o parâmetro e depois inserir ele no campo desejado
Veja o código à seguir pra inserir os campos "nome" e "nascimento" no html que eu usei no exemplo anterior:

```
    // Campos que você quer pegar e exibir na página
    let nome = getParameterByName('nome');
    document.querySelector("#nome").innerHTML += nome;
    let nascimento = getParameterByName('nascimento');
    document.querySelector("#nascimento").innerHTML += nascimento;
```

Nesse caso, a sua url precisaria ser algo como `http://127.0.0.1/pagina2.html?nome=Fulano&nascimento=01/01/1990` para poder exibir o nome e o nascimento nos campos

Caso você queira adicionar mais campos, terá que adicionar mais variaveis que salvam os parâmetros e mais blocos de inserção no html, como esse exemplo pra inserir o cpf no `<span id="cpf"></span>`

Para inserir o cpf:

```
    let cpf = getParameterByName('cpf');
    document.querySelector("#cpf").innerHTML += cpf;
```

Lembrando que pra exibir o cpf, a sua url precisaria ser algo como: `http://127.0.0.1/pagina2.html?cpf=ExemploDeCPF`

Comment: Eu devo colocar os id's da pag 2 igual aos da pag 1?

Comment: Não é obrigatório, mas se quiser, fica mais fácil pra você entender :)

Comment: Não deu certo!!

Comment: Poderia postar o código da página 2? gostaria de ver como você implementou :)

Comment: JassRiver, agora deu certo, corrigi meu erro. O código da página 2 é o que está postado. Meu erro: O name da var sn é o name do input da página 1, eu estava colocando o da 2. Mas acontece uma coisa que eu não quero aconteça nessa página que estou usando: Quando o formulário é submetido, automaticamente ele vai para página 2. Eu não quero que ele faça isso, porque a página 2 é um PDF e eu vou tentar fazer que, quando o formulário seja submetido, automaticamente, ele envie o PDF para o email que solicitarei no formulário. Eu já tenho um sistema desse, mas usando o google sheets.

Comment: @jairoolindino para envio de email, você iria precisar de uma linguagem server-side, como PHP, com ela, você poderia fazer o envio deste PDF para o email do formulário :)

Comment: Com js tbm dá. Eu uso esse código no google sheets: o metodo getBlob
var pdf1 = DriveApp.getFileById(wb.getId()).getAs("application/pdf").getBytes();
var anexo1 = {fileName:"",content:pdf1, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

  // aqui é a rotina de envio de email
  MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: data[data.length - 1], 
     cc: "",
     subject: "",
    htmlBody: "<h2>SIMULADO</h2>",
    name: '',

    attachments: [anexo1]

   });

//chama a pagina de retorno . Sucesso
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('').getContent();
}

Comment: @jairoolindino que daora! eu não conhecia esse método! vou procurar saber sobre, mas, no mais, a sua dúvida foi resolvida, ou tem algo mais que eu possa te ajudar?

Comment: A primeira sim. Agora eu só quero que quando o form for submetido o usuário não seja levado pra página do PDF, ele deve ser redirecionado para uma pagina de obrigado.